# Lodash import gives error in Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, lodash, require

I'm just starting to experiment with Node.js and Object Oriented Programming in Javascript.

This is my node based project structure [image]

This is my package.json file:
[image]

I'm trying to use lodash in my app.js file. For that, I'm trying to do :

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

but this gives me error: [image]

I tried another approach first to import lodash using :

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

But this also gave me an error:
[image]

I'm trying to understand what's the difference in the two imports(I think the 1st one is the way to do it in ES6 modules approach). Which one is used when. And why does it not work in my application? What is the correct way to use lodash in my application? I'm sure these are pretty basic questions but everywhere I'm looking, it shows one of the above two approaches to load lodash and they're not working for me.

Comment: Are you running this in the browser? Are you doing any kind of transpilation first?

Comment: I'm running it in browser, not doing any transpilation. I did npm install lodash --save before using it. I understand the require error is bcoz of running it in browser.

Comment: but does it mean we cant use lodash if we need to do anything with data on our html page?

Comment: @clever_bassi Are you intending to make a browser application or a Node.JS application? If Node, then you need to run `node app.js` from the terminal to run the node application. NodeJS is used to create "server-side" applications that run in the terminal.

Comment: I want to create a browser application. I'm running it using "npm run dev". I'm starting to understand your point. So for browser application, how would I import lodash in my Javascript class?

Comment: just add it using <script> tag in index.html and use ASM to load it in the file you need it

Comment: I already did that but I was wondering if there is more "nodejs" way to do this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any javascript code that gets executed in the browser and requires lodash the easiest way to do it is just to have a `<script>` tag in your html before your code runs:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>`

Then you don't need to require or import lodash in your app.js file. The example above loads lodash from an external CDN. To load it from your own application just change the `src` attribute to point to where your node.js app is serving the lodash library from.

If you want to use require or import statements in your client javascript code there are build tools and transpilers that replace the require or important statements in your source code to code that will work in the browser. This is saved into another file and then you run that file in your browser.  **Browserify**, **Webpack** and **Babel** are some you might want to look into, but if you are just starting out you may want to do that sometime down the road when you are building more complex applications.

Comment: I'm using Browserify now. Thank you.